# Usage lstinline in longtable

Tags: tables, listings, longtable

I'd like to format special words within a table with monospace font formatting. I thought would work was the usage `\lstinline{code}`. Although, this seems not work within a table as the compiler fails.

Is there a way using `lstinline` to achieve this? Or are there any alternatives?

Example code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tablestyles}
\usepackage{listings}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{*{2}{p{0.25\textwidth}p{0.75\textwidth}}}
\theadstart
    \thead Bezeichner \\ 
\tbody
    \lstinline{Akteur} \\ 
\tend
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\verb` can be used in a normal table cell, but it seems `\lstinline` cannot. Correction: the `\lstinline{...}` form cannot, but `\lstinline|...|` does work

Comment: Confirmed: `\lstinline{Akteur}` failes, `\lstinline|Akteur|` works.

Comment: Does not work on my side though, could you provide a screenshot / or the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tablestyles}
\usepackage{listings}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{*{2}{p{0.25\textwidth}p{0.75\textwidth}}}
\theadstart
    \thead Bezeichner \\ 
\tbody
    \lstinline|Akteur| \\ 
\tend
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

note `|...|` not `{...}` for `\lstinline`, then it compiles just fine (using TL2022) with this result

[image]

No idea whether it is suppose to look like that 8-)

Comment: hmm ok, it compiles. But afaik this is no monospace font :(

Comment: @Remo `listings` does not use monospace unless you ask for it. Never has. I think you need to configure `basicstyle` or similar. It is in the `listings` manual.

Comment: Aah, I see. Ok - since I use some code styles, I might know where the issue lies. Thanks for your input, I'd probably need to change some imports then :)